# What does 17|nq mean in terms of cases?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

So I am working on a proof where I end up with $17|nq$ where $n$ is a natural number and $q$ is an integer. I want to show $q$ is divisible by 17 for all $n$ and $q$. I think I can prove the statement once I know what $17|nq$ implies in terms of possible cases and how I can get to $17|q$

short part from the proof:  By lemma $\omega$, since $17|(nq)^2$, $17|nq$ thus we can express $nq$ as $nq=17 \tau$ with $\tau \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: You need $17\nmid n$ to conclude that, since $\,17\mid nq\iff 17\mid n$ or $17\mid q\,$ (by unique factorization and primality of $17)..\,$ You already used that in $\,17\mid m^2\,\Rightarrow\,17\mid m$

Comment: @billdubuque thanks then I think i already know where the proof is going.

Comment: As it stands there is not enough information to conclude what you want.

Comment: "I want to show q is divisible by 17 for all n and q. "  You can't because that isn't true.  If $n = 17$ and $q =3$ then $17|nq$ but $17\not \mid q$.  Perhaps you are not putting this in the right words?  If $q$ is specific integer and you know that $17|nq$ for all natural $n$ then you can prove $17|q$ simply by selecting $n = 1$.  Or maybe you want the conclusion $17|q$ *OR* $17|n$.  That *is* true because $17$ is prime and Euclid's lemma.